# Modify parameter values of sections in INI files Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ini, configparser

I have a .ini file which I want to modify a particular section.
So for example,

```
[Section1]
Param1: Hello
Param2: World

[Section2]
fontsize = 10

[Section3]
integers = 971 508 1076 561
```

I want to modify the integers in section 3 and replace them with other integers. I have tried:

```
lis = "971 508 1076 561; 920 543 973 648 ; 831 492 936 544 ; 936 403 988 508"
config.set('sfr',lis)
```

But I'm getting errors; how can I fix this?

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("C:\\Users\\Folder\\example.ini")
print(config.sections())
lis = "971 508 1076 561; 920 543 973 648 ; 831 492 936 544 ; 936 403 988 508"
config.set('sfr',lis)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could flesh out the code a little more as the snippet you have provided is of little use, ie. I to get errors with just those 2 lines in a python script.

Comment: Will that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the section and field to change the values of, try with:

```
config.set("Section3", "integers", lis)
```

Keep in mind that after changing the values you still need to save your config:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\Folder\\example.ini", "w") as f:
    config.write(f)
```